# Using Alive! to create a plugin for source engine?

Tags: ide, artificial-intelligence, game-engine

I am working on creating a form of AI that I would like to implement in a game that uses the source engine. I was wondering if I could use Alive! to create a plugin for the source engine as opposed to stock AI in the source engine?
Possible?
Practical?

Let me know what you think, I'm not overly familiar with the source engine's stock AI, thanks!